# error in applying gamma in open cv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to apply power of 2 to an image, But the output image is something different. This is  my 
code:

```
double val = 2;
cv::Mat src = imread("123.png",0);
cv::Mat dest ( src.size(), CV_8UC1);
for( int i=0; i<src.rows; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<src.cols; j++)
        dest.at<uchar>(i,j) = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(std::pow(src.at<uchar>(i,j),val));
```

I dint know what is the mistake i am doing, Help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code and it works!!
Instead of using cv::saturate_cast, I had used explicit conversion with "int"
used,
    `dest.at<uchar>(i,j) = (int) (255* std::pow(src.at<uchar>(i,j),val))`
instead of using,
    `dest.at<uchar>(i,j) = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>(std::pow(src.at<uchar>(i,j),val))`